# Angular2 view not getting updated in a callback with firebase authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using the following code for Email/Passwd authentication with firebase.
In case of error, I'm updating the error variable to display the error message. However, the view doesn't get updated. I have never seen problems with view not getting updated with angular2. 
Why ? and How do I fix this ?

```
login() {
 var parentThis = this;
 firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
 .catch((error) => {
    parentThis.error = error.message;
  })
}
```

I understand, there are some similar questions on SO..but, none of them explain why it's happening only in this case.

Comment: Sounds like a change detection issue. Do you load the Firebase SDK client before you load `zone.js`?

Comment: What firebase library are you using? Pure JS or https://github.com/angular/angularfire2?

Comment: in this case, I was using pure JS. I'll try with angularfire2 and update

Comment: It works fine with angularfire2. Thanks. Not sure, why it doesn't with pure JS.